# Can I build an index to an associative array from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

In my JavaScript code I have an associative (two dimension) array (`myObj[x][y]`), that has in every row n elements (I know n for every row - different in every row) where the first value show the amount (n) like

```
{"amount"=>"n", "key0"=>"value0","key1"=>"value1"..."keyn"=>"valuen"}
```

In a loop I need to access all these values like

```
for (i=o; i=n-1;i++){
  current=myObj[row-x].key-y; //code to do something with current
}
```

How can I build this index `.key-y` so I can access values? (If I create a string like `"myObj[row-x].key-"+ i.toString()}"` (where that construct the index as literal) can be done in some way?

JSON ```

"[{\"object_type\":\"villa\",\"object_name\":\"Villa at Maries\",\"object_id\":\"1\",\"mainimg\":\"images\/maries\/IMG1.jpg\",\"object_descreption\":\"BLA BLA BLA.\",\"smallimg0\":\"images\/maries\/img1f.jpg\",\"smallimg1\":\"images\/maries\/img1a.jpg\",\"smallimg2\":\"images\/maries\/img1b.jpg\",\"smallimg3\":\"images\/maries\/img1c.jpg\",\"amencount\":4,\"amenitie0\":\"A\/C\",\"amenitie1\":\"Kitchen\",\"amenitie2\":\"Wi Fi\",\"amenitie3\":\"Parking\"},{\"object_type\":\"villa\",\"object_name\":\"Villa at Agia Marina\",\"object_id\":\"2\",\"mainimg\":\"images\\agiamarina\\img1.jpg\",\"object_descreption\":BLA BLA BLA\",\"smallimg0\":\"images\/agiamarina\/img1.jpg\",\"smallimg1\":\"images\/agiamarina\/img2.jpg\",\"smallimg2\":\"images\/agiamarina\/img3.jpg\",\"smallimg3\":\"images\/agiamarina\/img4.jpg\",\"amencount\":3,\"amenitie0\":\"A\/C\",\"amenitie1\":\"Wi Fi\",\"amenitie2\":\"Parking\"},{\"object_type\":\"villa\",\"object_name\":\"Villa at Argasi\",\"object_id\":\"6\",\"mainimg\":\"images\/argasi\/img1.jpg\",\"object_descreption\":\"BLA BLA BLA\",\"smallimg0\":\"images\/argasi\/img1.jpg\",\"smallimg1\":\"images\/argasi\/img2.jpg\",\"smallimg2\":\"images\/argasi\/img3.jpg\",\"smallimg3\":\"images\/argasi\/img4.jpg\"}]"```

Thank you all !! got my answer.. so simple and so silly me !!!!!!!!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript. What you're looking for/talking about is an object -> [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Is `x` and `y` in `myObj` always numeric? Then you have a two-dimensional array and that's fine. If either is not, then you likely have an object with properties that are objects, an object with properties that are arrays, or an array of objects. Hard to say without seeing actual data. Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 2))` and [edit] your question to include the result.

Comment: well practically is a JSON that i transfer from php. i ve looked there, not found an answer.. still like that any suggestions ???

Comment: We need to know what your real data looks like in order to help you navigate it. We can guess, as the current answer does, but that's just a guess, based on the pseudo code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Something like this will loop through all your elements:

```
var rowAmount;
for (row=0; row < myObj.length; row++) {
    rowAmount = myObj[row].amount;
    for (key=0; key < myObj[row].length - 1; key++) {
        currentValue = myObj[row]["key" + key];
        //code to do something with currentValue and rowAmount
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all !! got my answer.. so simple and so silly me !!!!!!!! special thanks to you paw !!!